# Select client ID by last two digits

Tags: sql, netezza

As the title sugest I'm just trying to filter my clients from a DB by their last two digits. Aactually I want to filter my clients by several 2 digit terminations (from 31 to 39)

Tried using **LIKE** but it did not work and I can't seem to find an answer.

```
SELECT Client_ID FROM DB WHERE Client_ID LIKE '%31' OR '%32'
```

Comment: remove $ from like it should work. And how look like the ID?

Comment: Where Substring (client_id, Len(client_id)-1,2) like '31'

Comment: please tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `regexp_like` would be better in this case

```sql
select client_id from DB
where regexp_like(client_id, '3[1-9]$')
```

Answer (score 1):

`OR` connects boolean expressions.  You are trying to write:

```
WHERE Client_ID LIKE '%31' OR Client_ID LIKE '%32'
```

This addresses the syntax problem in the query in your question.

One alternative is:

```
WHERE STRRIGHT(Client_ID, 2) BETWEEN '30' and '39'
```

However, regular expressions as proposed in the other answer are probably the best choice.